# When will the xcm-executor implement something on the instr `HrmpNewChannelOpenRequest`?

Tags: xcm, xcmp, hrmp, executor

I want to have some automatic handling for channel opening requests.
I can do this by executing some logic when the relay sends an `HrmpNewChannelOpenRequest` instruction, but the default xcm-executor has an "Unimplemented" error returning.

Should I just fork the executor and put my custom logic there, or is it planned at some point soon to have some new generic types where we can decide what to do when that instruction is received?